# Identifier is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I wrote the following code in C++ using VS2012 Express.

```
void ac_search(
    uint num_patterns, uint pattern_length, const char *patterns, 
    uint num_records, uint record_length, const char *records,
    int *matches, Node* trie) {

  // Irrelevant code omitted.
}    

vector<int> ac_benchmark_search(
    uint num_patterns, uint pattern_length,
    const char *patterns, uint num_records, uint record_length,
    const char *records, double &time) {

  // Prepare the container for the results
  vector<int> matches(num_records * num_patterns);
  Trie T;
  Node* trie = T.addWord(records, num_records, record_length);

  // error line
  ac_search(num_patterns, pattern_length, patterns, num_records,
            record_length, records, matches.data(), trie);    

  // Irrelevant code omitted.    
  return matches;
}
```

I get the error `identifier "ac_search" is undefined` at the function invoking line. I am a bit confused here. because the function `ac_search` is declared as a global (not inside any container). Why can't I call it at this place? Am I missing something?

**Update**

I tried ignore irrelevant code and then included it gradually and found that everything is fine until I include the outer loop of `ac_search` I get the aforementioned error. here is updated code of the function `ac_search`:

```
void ac_cpu_string_search(uint num_patterns, uint pattern_length, const char *patterns, 
                       uint num_records, uint record_length, const char *records, int *matches, Node* trie)
{
    // Loop over all records
    //for (uint record_number = 0; record_number < num_records; ++record_number)
    //{
    //    // Loop over all patterns
        for (uint pattern_number = 0; pattern_number < num_patterns; ++pattern_number)
        {
            // Execute string search
            const char *ptr_record = &records[record_number * record_length];
            const char *ptr_match = std::strstr(ptr_record, &patterns[pattern_number * pattern_length]);

            // If pattern was found, then calculate offset, otherwise result is -1
            if (ptr_match)
            {
                matches[record_number * num_patterns + pattern_number] = static_cast<int>(std::distance(ptr_record, ptr_match));
            }
            else
            {
                matches[record_number * num_patterns + pattern_number] = -1;
            }
    //    }
    //}
}
```

**Update 2**

I think the error has something to do with the function `addWord` which belongs to the class `Trie`. When I commented out this function, I did not get the error anymore.

```
Node* Trie::addWord(const char *records, uint num_records, uint record_length)
{

    // Loop over all records
    for (uint record_number = 0; record_number < num_records; ++record_number)
    {
        const char *ptr_record = &records[record_number * record_length];
        string s = ptr_record;
        Node* current = root;
        if ( s.length() == 0 )
        {
            current->setWordMarker(); // an empty word
            return;
        }

        for ( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++ )
        {        
            Node* child = current->findChild(s[i]);
            if ( child != NULL )
            {
                current = child;
            }
                else
                {
                    Node* tmp = new Node();
                    tmp->setContent(s[i]);
                    current->appendChild(tmp);
                    current = tmp;
                }
                if ( i == s.length() - 1 )
                    current->setWordMarker();
        }
        return current;
    }  

void ac_search(
        uint num_patterns, uint pattern_length, const char *patterns, 
        uint num_records, uint record_length, const char *records,
        int *matches, Node* trie) {

      // Irrelevant code omitted.
    }    

    vector<int> ac_benchmark_search(
        uint num_patterns, uint pattern_length,
        const char *patterns, uint num_records, uint record_length,
        const char *records, double &time) {

      // Prepare the container for the results
      vector<int> matches(num_records * num_patterns);
      Trie T;
      Node* trie = T.addWord(records, num_records, record_length);

      // error line
      ac_search(num_patterns, pattern_length, patterns, num_records,
                record_length, records, matches.data(), trie);    

      // Irrelevant code omitted.    
      return matches;
    }
```

Comment: Check that `ac_search` is declared earlier than definition of `ac_benchmark_search`

Comment: Can you try making `ac_search` static? Or put `ac_search` as extern to the header file.

Comment: @SergeyKolotienko yes, the code is quoted as it is, same order

Comment: @LeventeKurusa I am not sure if I have to do anything except adding the keyword `extern` in front of the `ac_search` definition? I tried same for `static` but it did not work

Comment: Try removing the irrelevant code, as I've shown in the edit. Please also show just enough code to make a complete, stand-alone example that should compile. The idea is to arrive at the smallest example that exhibits the problem; then you'll have less to debug.

Comment: @AdamLiss I've followed your advise, the post updated accordingly

Comment: @hawk Take a close look at that posted code update, specifically, the number of commented-out *open braces* (`{`) and the number of commented out *closing braces* (`}`). It cannot possible compile as is because (a) There is no declaration of `record_number` in-scope. and (b) You commented out ONE open-brace, but TWO close-braces. This tells me somewhere in the code immediately *below* this is an extra closing brace that shouldn't be there. How you're compiling using an undeclared variable is beyond me.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, but the bracket issue was just typo. I've updated the post

Comment: AddWord seems to be missing a closing brace.

Comment: @ta.speot.is  
Yes, That is correct. Thanks for all, every comment narrowed down the problem. Was not expected that brace can cause identifier undefined error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the update 2 and after narrowing down the problem scope, we can easily find that there is a brace missing at the end of the function `addWord`. The compiler will never explicitly identify such a syntax error. instead, it will assume that the missing function definition located in some other object file. The linker will complain about it and hence directly will be categorized under one of the broad the error phrases which is `identifier is undefined`. Reasonably, because with the current syntax the next function definition (in this case is `ac_search`) will be included under the `addWord` scope. Hence, it is not a global function anymore. And that is why compiler will not see this function outside `addWord` and will throw this error message stating that there is no such a function. A very good elaboration about the compiler and the linker can be found in this [article](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html)

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing a function declaration?

```
void ac_search(uint num_patterns, uint pattern_length, const char *patterns, 
               uint num_records, uint record_length, const char *records, int *matches, Node* trie);
```

Add it just before your implementation of ac_benchmark_search.

Comment: This shouldn't matter if the function is implemented before the other is implemented.

Comment: "if" is the important part.

Comment: Looking at his code, it is ac_benchmark_search *is* implemented before ac_search, unless he posted it the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe he pasted here just these two functions (in the right order).

Comment: @user1764961 I posted the same order as my code implementation

Comment: @hawk, no namespaces?

Comment: @user1764961 I've used namespace   `using namespace concurrency;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;`

Answer (score -7):

You may also be missing `using namespace std;`